# Virtual call crash

Tags: c++, function, pointers, crash

```
class AbstractEffect{
public:
   AbstractEffect() : _id(AbstractEffect::generateID()){}

   virtual void update() const{
       LOG("Base class Update");
   }

   void nonVirtualCall() const{
       LOG("Test call");
   }


   private:
   const int _id;

   static int generateID(){ static int id= 0; return id++; }
}

class EffectImpl : public AbstractEffect{
public:
    EffectImpl(){}

    virtual void update() const{
         LOG("Impl update");
    } 
}

class Adapter{
public:
      Adapter(const AbstractEffect* effect) : _effect(effect) { }

void update(){
     LOG("This " << this);
     LOG("Effect address " << _effect);
     _effect->nonVirtualCall(); // dummy call I made to see what happens
     _effect->update(); // virtual function call
}

private:
    const AbstractEffect* const _effect; 
}
```

Adapter class. Update() gets called. Output:

```
This 04155D90
Effect address 006F4A58
Test Call
Impl update
```

Next iteration (next game loop update), same Adapter, Update() gets called. Output:

```
This 04155D90
Effect address 0020F65C
Test Call
```

... and there it crashes(Access violation) at the update virtual call. As you can see it is the same adapter class, but a different effect, even though I have defined it as const *. I have examined the object's property values in both calls. In first _id is 0 (as it should be), in second it's an eight digit number (68509216 for example). I have put a breakpoint on effect's destructor to make sure the object isn't destroyed.

How can const AbstractEffect* const point to a different object? How can it crash on a virtual call and execute the non-virtual call successfully ?

Comment: It looks like you're getting some sort of memory corruption.  Either that, or these aren't actually the same object but rather temporary values that happen to allocate at the same location (say, because they're on the stack and end up in the same stack slot because it's the same call chain every time).

Comment: You might consider a breakpoint on Adapter's destructor...

Comment: In the case of a temporary, it's destructor would be called as soon as the function returned. Regarding adapter, it's destructor isn't called. If it was, it'd crash on update() call of Adapter, not Effect since I'd be trying to call update on a dangling pointer.

Comment: In any case, because your `AbstractEffect *` isn't pointing to the right place, your non-virt method call succeeds because it doesn't need a virt table for dispatch _and_ the method involved doesn't actually look at `this`.  (If it did look at `this`, it would be horrified.)  The virt method crashes because the pointer is invalid, and so the virt table lookup gives the access violation.  (Usually the virt table is hidden in the first bytes of the class structure.)